# How to calculate the complexity of a "not so simple" program?

Tags: algorithm, asymptotic-complexity

I know how to calculate the complexity of a program whenever there is a variable declaration or some simple loops are involved (i.e a linear case ) by counting the number of times each line will be executed.

But in some cases I see that some lines of code run logarithmically,exponentially,in a cubic order,etc, I just want to know how can I figure that out?

Comment: perhaps a question for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: if you "see" already that something is logarithmically etc., what´s the problem
?

Comment: I don't "see" that, I just get that from the solution provided to the problem, I can't figure out that its logarithmic by my own.

Comment: The question is a bit broad; however, if complexity could always be "calculated" right away, there were no papers in theoretical computer science filling pages with (sometimes quite involved) arguments doing a "runtime analysis".

Comment: The complexity of some complex algorithms can be found with the master theorem http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem

Comment: And, sometimes, you just have to time a series of tests and run a curve-fitting algorithm against the data series to find out what kind of trend it's following...

Answer (score 1):

> The [following][3] figure dices up the analysis of runtime of the merge sort algorithm:
> We split the original array into two arrays of size n / 2 each. Then we merge those arrays, an operation that merges n elements and thus takes Θ( n ) time.
> By this argument, the complexity for each row is Θ( n ). We know that the number of rows in this diagram, also called the depth of the recursion tree, will be log( n ). The reasoning for this is exactly the same as the one we used when analyzing the complexity of binary search. We have log( n ) rows and each of them is Θ( n ), therefore the complexity of mergeSort is Θ( n * log( n ) )

---

> Simple programs can be analyzed by counting the nested loops of the program. A single loop over n items yields f( n ) = n. A loop within a loop yields f( n ) = n2. A loop within a loop within a loop yields f( n ) = n3.
>
> Given a series of for loops that are sequential, the slowest of them determines the asymptotic behavior of the program. Two nested loops followed by a single loop is asymptotically the same as the nested loops alone, because the nested loops dominate the simple loop.

---

```
 i := 1;
while ( i < n )  
  i = i * 2;
```

> The running time is logarithmic, O(logn) because of the multiplication by 2.

Few useful links are:
https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/192/how-to-come-up-with-the-runtime-of-algorithms

I hope they help you!